# laravel xml parser error

Tags: xml, laravel, parsing

this is my xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
   <elenco_clienti>
     <cliente>
      <cod>00001</cod>
      <name>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</name>
      <address>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</address>
    </cliente>
    <cliente>
    <cod>00003</cod>
      <name>mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm</name>
      <address>iiiiiiiiiiii</address>
    </cliente>
   </elenco_clienti>
```

and this is my controller

```
 <?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 use Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Facade as XmlParser;
 use App\Clienti;
 use Illuminate\Container\Container;
 use Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Document as OrchestraDocument;
 use Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Reader as OrchestraReader;
 class XmlController extends Controller

 {

public function importFilexml(Request $request){        
    if($request->hasFile('sample_file')){           
        $path = $request->file('sample_file')->getRealPath();       
        //$xml = XmlParser::extract($path);     
        //print_r($xml);
      $app = new Container;
        $document = new OrchestraDocument($app);
        $reader = new OrchestraReader($document);
        $xml = $reader->load($path);
        $conto = count($xml);

    $user = $xml->parse([
                'cod' => ['uses' => 'cliente.cod'],
                'name' => ['uses' => 'cliente.name'],
                'address' => ['uses' => 'cliente.address'],                                                                                                                                                                         
        ]); 
                print_r($user);         
                if(!empty($user)){              
                    DB::table('clientis')->insert($user);                   
                dd('Insert Recorded successfully.');                    
            }               
        }       
    dd('Request data does not have any files to import.');      
}



}
```

the problem is that: only the value of the first customer is stored in the variable. i can not access to all xml file.
why?
The xml object not contain all xml file, i'm not view the item property

and this is my object

```
   Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Document Object 
 ( 
  [app:protected] => Illuminate\Container\Container Object 
   ( 
    [resolved:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [bindings:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [methodBindings:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [instances:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [aliases:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [abstractAliases:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [extenders:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [tags:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [buildStack:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [with:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [contextual] => Array ( ) 
    [reboundCallbacks:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [globalResolvingCallbacks:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [globalAfterResolvingCallbacks:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [resolvingCallbacks:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [afterResolvingCallbacks:protected] => Array ( ) ) 
 [namespaces:protected] => 
 [content:protected] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
 ( 
  [cliente] => Array ( 
  [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
 [cod] => 00001 
 [name] => My name
 [address] => My address

[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ....
```

why is protected?
how do I access this object?
i'm try whith foreach ($xml->content->cliente as $item => $value){
but don't work
any suggestion please

Comment: Your code doesn't include any loop to iterate through all of the <cliente>'s. I guess that's why you only see the first one.

Comment: but the xml object don't have any item

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](http://tuttolospazio.com/farmaraf/image.png).

Answer (score 0):

As @Amarnasan says, your code doesn't include any loop to iterate through all of the *cliente*'s. To correctly parse that XML, an example controller would be (using last version of the [Xmlparser library](https://github.com/orchestral/parser), as of Feb. 2018):

```
use Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Facade as XmlParser;

class XmlController extends Controller
{
    public function importFilexml(Request $request) { 

        if($request->hasFile('sample_file')) {     
            $xml = XmlParser::load($request->file('sample_file')->getRealPath());
            $elenco_clienti = $xml -> parse([
                'cod' => ['uses' => 'elenco_clienti.cliente[cod]'],
                'name' => ['uses' => 'elenco_clienti.cliente[name]'],
                'address' => ['uses' => 'elenco_clienti.cliente[address]']                
            ]);
            ...
            // DB inserts and other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Thus, you would get the information of all *cliente*'s correctly parsed :)